# Powershell: recurse directories for where a file extension exists if Exist write out comman if not run a command

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, splunk, spl

Specifically, I have a directory with a ton of other random named directories (Not really random but that's not important). In those directories some contain files with a `.tsidx` extension, some do not.

The directories which contain the `.tsidx` extension I want to output to screen that a `.tsidx` file already exists.  The ones that do NOT I want it to output it doesn't exist then run a command to build the tsidx files against the directory using an executable provided by avendor of a program.

Here is what is in my code so far:

```
$index = Read-Host "Enter the Index Name" #This is to receive a directory  location from user
$loc = "F:\thawdb\splunk\$index\thaweddb"
$dir = dir $loc

cd "d:\splunk\bin"
foreach ($d in $dir) 
{
   if (gci -dir | ? { !(gci $_ -file -recur -filter *tsidx) })
      {
         # writes out the directory contains files and doesn't need rebuilt
         Write-host -foregroundcolor Yellow "TSIDX Exists"
      }
      else
      {
         # writes out rebuild is necessary and runs the rebuild
         write-host -Foregroundcolor Green "Running Rebuild command against $loc\$d" | .\splunk.exe rebuild $loc\$d 
      }
}
```

Comment: [1] something is wrong with your code - the two `writes out` lines are breaking it into separate sections. would you please, fix it? ///// [2] so ... what is not working? your code LOOKS like it will do what you describe.

Comment: Looks like Theo edited it?

Comment: Yes, I did edit so the code becomes readable. I also added some whitespace in the question itself if you don't mind. If you think I ruined the question by doing so, please edit yourself.

Comment: @Theo - thanks for the fix! [*grin*]

Comment: @JeffFunderburg - in addition to the `& splunk.exe` answer from theo, you may want to look at `Start-Process`. it adds a few extra things that you may find useful - look into the methods the returned object provides.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - IS that to perform parallelization.. because I run this against a directory containing from 100- hundreds of thousands of directories and parellilizing hundreds of throusands of directorieds MIGHT be bad... although I am considering ways to do it....

Comment: @JeffFunderburg - nope, it aint about parallel stuff, it's just another way to call external utils that gives you a bit more "stuff" to fiddle with. for instance, the object has a `-RunAs` parameter. take a look at `(Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter *).Name` for the parameter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no idea what `splunk.exe` does, I think this should do it:

```
$index = Read-Host "Enter the Index Name" #This is to receive a directory  location from user
$loc = "F:\thawdb\splunk\$index\thaweddb"

# get a collection of DirInfo objects for all directories in the path
$dir = Get-ChildItem $loc -Directory -Recurse

Set-Location "d:\splunk\bin"

# loop through the DirInfo collection
foreach ($d in $dir) {
   if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $d.FullName -File -Filter '*.tsidx').Count) {
         # writes out the directory contains files and doesn't need rebuilt
         Write-host -foregroundcolor Yellow "TSIDX Exists in $($d.FullName)"
    }
    else {
        # writes out rebuild is necessary and runs the rebuild
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "Running Rebuild command against $($d.FullName)" 
        & .\splunk.exe rebuild "$($d.FullName)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Will test it out.  Basically Splunk is a Log analysis software.  tsidk Are index files.  the command I am running is taking data that had indexes remoed for Long term storage and re=indexing the data.

Comment: @JeffFunderburg Aha, It didn't ring any bell, but now I know.

Comment: I ran it with the Write-out and colors and NOT the executable as a test and it seemed to assign the correct names and colors.  Going to add executable in now.  Thanks, this script will save me Literally DAYS worth of work every time I have to re-index data I had Archived!!!!